# Powershell - Getting list member value

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

In the below snippet, I am trying to append the $roleName (as Role) from the outer list $admin_roles to the file.
That role always shows up empty (other columns are fine). What am I missing?

```
Connect-MsolService
$output_file_location = "c:\temp\azure_admins_mfa_status_"+$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)+".csv"
$admin_roles = "Company Administrator","Billing Administrator","Conditional Access Administrator","Exchange Service administrator","Helpdesk administrator","Password administrator","Security administrator","Sharepoint Service administrator"

# Gets all the members in the admin roles in the roles list above
# Gets the MFA status for each member
# Appends the below data points to a file specified in the $output_file_location variable 
# DisplayName,E-mail,Role,MFA-Requirements, MFA-Methods, MFA-MethodsDefault
function get-mfa-status
{
    foreach ($roleName in $admin_roles)
    {
        write-output $roleName
        $members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $(Get-MsolRole -RoleName $roleName).ObjectId
        #write-output $members
        foreach ($member in $members) 
        {
            write-output $member.EmailAddress
            
        }
        
        foreach ($member in $members) 
        { 
        Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $member.EmailAddress | select DisplayName, `
        @{N='E-mail';E={$_.userPrincipalName}}, `
        {N='Role';E={$roleName}}, `
        @{N='MFA-Requirements';E={(($_).StrongAuthenticationRequirements.state)}}, `
        @{N='MFA-Methods';E={(($_).StrongAuthenticationMethods.MethodType)}}, `
        @{N='MFA-MethodsDefault';E={($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods | where isdefault -eq 'true').MethodType}} `
        | select DisplayName,E-mail,Role,MFA-Requirements, MFA-Methods, MFA-MethodsDefault| Export-Csv $output_file_location -Append `
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing `@` before `{N='Role';E={$roleName}}`

Comment: Thank you @robdy. Feel free to add this an answer and I will accept.

Comment: btw, just a formatting comment. Those graveyard accents (backticks) are not really needed, since the comma is a natural continuation character (just as operators and the like are), and the pipe is a natural continuation as long as you have it on the same line as the code to the left of it. Het, but if are ok with them, then you do you. See this: [Bye Bye Backtick: Natural Line Continuations in PowerShell](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html). It's got many good points, though I don't really agree with all of the authors stated positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing `@` before `{N='Role';E={$roleName}}`. Usually, you'd notice that immediately as it'd show the column name as the whole expression.

However, due to second `Select-Object`, you're not seeing that. PowerShell selects the column named `Role`. As it doesn't exist, you see empty column.

Side note: I think the second `Select-Object` is not necessary. Skipping it will result in the same output (provided you corrected broken expression as mentioned above).